# difference between Not In and <> or <>

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any difference in the below 2 codes, i am getting a huge difference in the output.

1)

```
SUM( 
CASE 
WHEN lientype.id NOT IN (-1, -3) THEN 
  ((a.floatingspread + dbo.maxfloat(a.floatingspreadfloor, al.liborrate)) * pos.marketvalue) 
  ELSE 0 
END)/NULLIF(sum( 
CASE 
WHEN lientype.id NOT IN (-1, 
                         -3) THEN 
  (pos.marketvalue) 
  ELSE 0 
END),0) averagecoupon
```

2)

```
SUM( 
CASE 
WHEN ( 
    lientype.id<>-1 
    OR 
    lientype.id<>-3 
  ) 
  THEN 
  ((a.floatingspread + dbo.maxfloat(a.floatingspreadfloor, al.liborrate)) * pos.marketvalue) 
  ELSE 0 
END)/NULLIF(sum( 
CASE 
WHEN ( 
    lientype.id<>-1 
    OR 
    lientype.id<>-3 
  ) 
  THEN 
  (pos.marketvalue) 
  ELSE 0 
END),0) averagecoupon
```

Comment: You should have "and" instead of "or", <> -1 or <> -3 is always true

Comment: The simple answer to your question is "Yes". Bad answer? Bad question.

Comment: If there is a huge difference in the output then yes, you can infer there is a difference.

Comment: That scalar function in the middle of a column is very scary. Scalar functions are notoriously bad for performance and when stuck in a column like that they can be crippling.

Comment: https://pogoprinciple.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/divide3.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The `NOT IN` for your case should translate into `<> -1 AND <> -3`. Having `<> -1 OR <> -3` roughly translates into `NOT IN (-1) OR NOT IN (-3)`, so the outputs would be very different.

Comment: @user5016908 - Please feel free to upvote an answer if it helped you and accept it if it solved your question. This helps others to know which answers may have helped and if any solved your question. It also increases your reputation.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
lientype.id<>-1 
OR 
lientype.id<>-3
```

should be:

```
lientype.id<>-1 
AND
lientype.id<>-3
```

in order to be equivalent to:

```
lientype.id NOT IN (-1, -3)
```

What you are doing now is just saying that `lientype.id is not -1 or it is not -3`, but it is obvious that it can not equal to both values at the same time, so it will be always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

When A and B are not equal themselves, all values are

not equal to A

or

not equal to B

Is like saying, "give me everything that's not `-1` and everything that's not `-3`." That's just the same as everything.

This is a pointless check that can be omitted.

Where as, `NOT IN (A, B)`

is equivalent to everything but A or B.

In your snippets you could sub-optimally write,

```
WHEN NOT (lientype.id = -1 OR lientype.id = -3)
```

as a direct logical substitute for

```
WHEN lientype.id NOT IN (-1, -3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
lientype.id NOT IN (-1, -3)
```

is equivalent to :

```
NOT (lientype.id = -1 OR lientype.id = -3)
```

which is also equivalent to :

```
lientype.id != -1 AND lientype.id != -3
```

or

```
lientype.id <> -1 AND lientype.id <> -3
```

When you 'distribute' the `NOT` across what is in the brackets, you need to 'flip' any boolean logic and comparison operators together (`AND -> OR`, `OR -> AND`, `= -> !=`, and `!= -> =`). You have reversed the equality operator (`= -> <>`), but not the boolean `OR`.

Comment: Just to add - `id NOT IN (-1, -3)` AND `(id != -1 AND id != -3)` are absolutely equivalent and will be treated identically by the query optimizer, which will produce the same execution plan for both, so it is better to use the `NOT IN` syntax, as it is clearer to read.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but you could still use `OR` but would need to use = and switch the `THEN` and `END`

```
SELECT
SUM( CASE 
     WHEN ( 
        lientype.id=-1 
        OR 
        lientype.id=-3 
      ) 
     THEN 0
     ELSE ((a.floatingspread + dbo.maxfloat(a.floatingspreadfloor, al.liborrate)) * pos.marketvalue) 
     END)
/NULLIF(SUM( 
     CASE 
     WHEN ( 
        lientype.id=-1 
        OR 
        lientype.id=-3 
        ) 
     THEN 0
     ELSE
        (pos.marketvalue) 
     END),0) averagecoupon -- DIVIDE BY ZERO?
```